# Выборка элемента через jquery

Tags: jquery

Как добавить в POST запрос значение из data-num и результат вернуть в таблицу в место None?

```js
function add_data_mod(e) {
  $.post("../api/datamodadd", {
    'dmodule': $('#datas_mod').val()
  });
  $('#datas_module').val('');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>None<br><input type="text" data-num="1" name="datas_mod" id="datas_mod" onkeypress="keypressed(event)" style="width: 40%"><button type="submit" onclick="add_data_mod()">Add</button><button type="submit" onclick="del_data_mod()">Del</button><br></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button.add").click(add_data_mod);

function add_data_mod(e) {
  var $cell = $(this).closest("td");
  var $inp = $cell.find(".datas_mod");
  var dataIn = {
    dmodule: $inp.val(),
    datanum: $inp.data("num")
  };
  console.log(dataIn);

  $.post("../api/datamodadd", dataIn, function(dataOut) {
    $cell.find("span.result").text(dataOut);
  });

  $inp.val('');
  return false;
}

function keypressed(e) {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="result">None</span>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" data-num="1" name="datas_mod" class="datas_mod" onkeypress="keypressed(event)" style="width: 40%">
      <button type="submit" class="add">Add</button>
      <button type="submit" class="del">Del</button>
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```